# Error compiling report java source files

Tags: java, jasper-reports

my probleme is: i can't compile my report from java.
well i create my page in iReport and i load it from my java code.

here is some of my error:

```
    5 juin 2011 19:45:47 org.apache.commons.digester.Digester error
GRAVE: Parse Error at line 3 column 408: Attribute "xmlns" must be declared for element type "jasperReport".
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute "xmlns" must be declared for element type "jasperReport".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.addDTDDefaultAttrsAndValidate(XMLDTDValidator.java:1275)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1940)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1363)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1318)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3103)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:922)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1647)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:238)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:225)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:213)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:167)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:151)
    at gestionstock.Recherche_commande.jButton2ActionPerformed(Recherche_commande.java:258)
    at gestionstock.Recherche_commande.access$300(Recherche_commande.java:36)
    at gestionstock.Recherche_commande$4.actionPerformed(Recherche_commande.java:151)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6263)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6028)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4574)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
5 juin 2011 19:45:47 gestionstock.Recherche_commande jButton2ActionPerformed
```

and here is my java code:

```
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:gpsi";
    String user = "gestion";
    String passwd = "password";
    Connection conn = null;

    String reference = this.commande_reference.getText();

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load("./lib/report.jrxml");
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
        Map parameters = new HashMap();

        parameters.put("ref",reference);        

         JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, conn);

        net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint,false);
        // - Création du rapport au format PDF
        //JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "./lib/report.pdf");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this , "Opération éffectuée avec succès!", "Terminé" , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE)  ;

    } catch (JRException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Recherche_commande.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "erreur : Opération non effectuées " +
                ex.getMessage()  , "Avertissement", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "erreur : Opération non effectuées " +
                ex.getMessage()  , "Avertissement", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }finally {
        try {
             conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

and finaly here is my jrxml file called report.jrxml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jasperReport PUBLIC "//JasperReports//DTD Report Design//EN" "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jasperreport.dtd">
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report2" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="ref" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
                ASSOCIER."QUANTITE",
                CLIENTS."CLIENTNOM",
                PRODUITS."PRODUITNOM",
                COMMANDES."REFERENCE",
                COMMANDES."COMMANDEDATE",
                CLIENTS."CLIENTPRENOM" AS CLIENTS_CLIENTPRENOM,
                sum(PRODUITS.produitprix*ASSOCIER.quantite)
        FROM
                "COMMANDES" COMMANDES,
                "EMPLOYES" EMPLOYES,
                "CLIENTS" CLIENTS,
                "PAIEMENTS" PAIEMENTS,
                "ASSOCIER" ASSOCIER,
                "PRODUITS" PRODUITS
        WHERE
                COMMANDES.employeid = EMPLOYES.employeid
                and CLIENTS.clientid = COMMANDES.clientid
                and COMMANDES.commandeid = PAIEMENTS.commandeid
                and COMMANDES.commandeid = ASSOCIER.commandeid
                and PRODUITS.produitid = ASSOCIER.produitid
                and COMMANDES.reference = '$P!{ref}'
        GROUP BY
                PRODUITS.produitnom,
                COMMANDES.reference,
                CLIENTS.clientnom,
                CLIENTS.clientprenom,
                EMPLOYES.employenom,
                COMMANDES.commandedate,
                PAIEMENTS.paiementdate,
                ASSOCIER.quantite]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="QUANTITE" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="CLIENTNOM" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="PRODUITNOM" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="REFERENCE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="COMMANDEDATE" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="CLIENTS_CLIENTPRENOM" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SUM(PRODUITS.PRODUITPRIX*ASSOCIER.QUANTITE)" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <group name="REFERENCE">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{REFERENCE}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="143" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="183" y="25" width="222" height="92"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Andalus" size="60"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Facture]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="15" y="121" width="527" height="1"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="2.0" lineStyle="Double"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="17" y="7" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Reference :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="310" y="9" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Date :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="127" y="7" width="100" height="20" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{REFERENCE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="423" y="7" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.sql.Timestamp"><![CDATA[$F{COMMANDEDATE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="17" y="10" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Nom de client :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="127" y="10" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{CLIENTNOM}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="307" y="10" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Prenom de  client :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="423" y="10" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{CLIENTS_CLIENTPRENOM}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="-19" y="30" width="595" height="1" forecolor="#666666"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="323" y="41" width="143" height="20" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[SUM(PRODUITS.PRODUITPRIX*ASSOCIER.QUANTITE)]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="204" y="41" width="119" height="20" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[QUANTITE]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="73" y="41" width="131" height="20" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[PRODUITNOM]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="49" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="73" y="0" width="131" height="20" backcolor="#9999FF"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{PRODUITNOM}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="324" y="0" width="142" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.math.BigDecimal"><![CDATA[$F{SUM(PRODUITS.PRODUITPRIX*ASSOCIER.QUANTITE)}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="204" y="0" width="120" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.math.BigDecimal"><![CDATA[$F{QUANTITE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="73" y="0" width="393" height="1"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="204" y="1" width="1" height="19"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="15" width="515" height="13" backcolor="#E6E6E6"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="515" y="15" width="40" height="13" backcolor="#E6E6E6"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                <reportElement x="0" y="15" width="100" height="13"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.util.Date"><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

for information im using:

```
iReport3.4.7
jasperreports-1.2.1.jar
iText-2.1.7.jar
commons-logging-api-1.0.2.jar
commons-logging-1.0.2.jar
commons-digester-1.7.jar
commons-collections-2.1.jar
commons-beanutils-1.5.jar
groovy-all-1.5.5.jar
```

I'll be thankfull !!!

after deleting the xmlns, i have that error:

```
5 juin 2011 21:18:10 org.apache.commons.digester.Digester error
GRAVE: Parse Error at line 62 column 30: Attribute "splitType" must be declared for element type "band".
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute "splitType" must be declared for element type "band".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using both the DTD and the XML schema, stick to the DTD alone. In other words, instead of having the following lines in your JRXML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE jasperReport PUBLIC "//JasperReports//DTD Report Design//EN" "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jasperreport.dtd">
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report2" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
```

you should instead have:

```
<!DOCTYPE jasperReport PUBLIC "//JasperReports//DTD Report Design//EN" "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jasperreport.dtd">
<jasperReport>
```

**Update**

Going by the fact that iReport 3.4.7 was being used to generate the JRXML file, to be used against JasperReports 1.2.1, it was evident that the generated JRXML file would not be validated correctly. Therefore, the fix is to use compatible versions of iReport and JasperReports.

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds: thanks for your answer, i just do what you ask me to do but i still have errors

Comment: @Optimmus, that attribute appears to be declared only in the XSD and not in the DTD, so use the XSD instead of the DTD. The original error was due to two schemas describing the same elements in the same namespace. You can have only one schema declare an element in a namespace; the XSD appears to be more recent and more apt for your JRXML file, given the recent error. So, you ought to use that.

Comment: @Optimmus, I ought to add that if both the DTD and XSD produce errors when they are used singly, then there is a problem with the contents of the JRXML file.

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds: hmm still the same error, well is my version of the jars and my iReport are compatible?

Comment: @Optimmus, the problem is not with the JARs. It is with the versions of the DTD and XSD files used. The splitType attribute is defined in the XSD, and not in the DTD. If you used the XSD, then you should not have the same error reported. However, I did point out that the JRXML file might not be valid, for it might use some elements defined only in the DTD, and others defined only in the XSD. This might be the case here. You will therefore have to create a JRXML file that is valid against the XSD alone, or the DTD alone.

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds: i tried to creat a new JRXML file but it's the same thing, how to create a JRXML file valid against just for XSD or DTD?
thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: @Optimmus, are you following any tutorial to create this file, or are you using any tool like iReport? In either case, you could manually verify if the contents of the created file would be valid considering the contents of [the JasperReports schema reference](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/schema.reference.html).

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds: yes im using iReport, and im tring to export data from database.

Comment: @Optimmus, I have the vague feeling that your iReport and JasperReports versions might not be compatible.

Comment: @Optimmus, you'll need iReport 1.2.1 for JasperReports 1.2.1. Those versions are quite old. You might want to obtain the most recent compatible versions of the JARs.

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds: i use iReport3.4.7 and jasperreports-1.2.1.jar

Comment: @Optimmus, that's what I meant by the fact that they're incompatible versions. iReport 3.4.7 (released in 2009) would be creating JRXML files that would be valid against a particular version of a XML schema. The same schema however might not be recognized by JasperReports 1.2.1 (which was released in 2006).

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds: okey i'll try jasperreports-3.5.3 i think it's compatible with iReport 3.4.7, right?

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds: thank you so much for help, it's work now :D
im really i appreciate your help !!!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error by adding the jdk bin directory into the environmental variables. Hope this helps someone.